# Como fazer um wordwrap dentro de um <pre>?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma tag `<pre>Oie</pre>`

eu queria que esse texto ficasse com largura máxima de 595px `word-wrap:break-word;`
o que fiz foi o seguinte

```
pre {
width:595px;
word-wrap:break-word;

}
```

Eu faço isso , mas não acontece nada, eu simplesmente aperto faço isso

```
<pre>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</pre>
```

e o texto não quebra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o estilo `white-space`, além do `word-wrap: break-word;`, para aplicar quebra de linha para strings longas dentro do `<pre>`:

```css
pre {
   width:595px;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   word-wrap: break-word;   
}
```

```html
<pre>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</pre>
```

Comment: nOSSA COMO VC SABIA disso? poxa esses codigos  sao dificeis vo anotar

Comment: @AndressaLimão A gente vai aprendendo. :)

Comment: @AndressaLimão Fiz uma atualização na resposta. Retirei os estilos prefixados, acho que não precisa disso.

Comment: Obrigada DVD, nossa eu nunca ouvi falar desse whitespace nenhum curso me ensinou :( programação é complicada

Comment: Pode me explicar o que é o white space? Pesquisei aqui na net a linguagem ta meio complicada :(

Comment: Poxa pode me exlicar o que é o whitespace?

Comment: @AndressaLimão Ele trata como os espaços em branco serão tratados dentro do elemento. O valor `pre-wrap;` preserva os espaços e quebra o texto quando necessário. Espaços em branco seriam: `olá_Mundo!` (1 espaço em branco entre "olá" e "Mundo"); `Oi_____você!` (5 espaços em branco entre as duas palavras)... o `pre-wrap;` deixa os espaços como estão.